# Stencil.js - Listen to class attribute changes on host element

Tags: web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

How do I listen to changes to the `class` attribute on the host element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easy way to do it, but that might not be appropriate in all situations.

Simply add 'class' as a @Prop and a @Watch:

```
@Prop() class: string;
@Watch('class') handleClassChange(class: string) {
    console.log(class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tracking DOM attribute changes requires the use of a `MutationObserver`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```js
componentDidLoad() {
    // Target element that will be observed
    const target = this.el;

    const config = {
        attributes: true,
        attributeOldValue: true,
        attributeFilter: ['class']
    };

    function subscriberCallback(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
            console.log(mutation);
        });
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver(subscriberCallback);
    observer.observe(target, config);
}
```

Comment: An alternative would be to define your own property (e.g. `cssClass`) with a watcher, and then manually setting the `class` of the host element.